# Unable to load requested field type file: ft.relationship.php. after updating

Tags: expressionengine

I upgraded my Expression Engine installation to 2.7.3 (from 2.3.1). But after upgrading I get an error when trying to view the site.

> Error
>
> Unable to load requested field type file:  ft.relationship.php.
>
> Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory

I can see that there is a expressionengine/fieldtypes/relationship/ft.relationship.php and if I go to the admin page I see a field type as being installed there (As “Relationships Version 1.0”).

Why is EE giving me an error at that point?

Comment: You might get some better success with your question over at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/.  But from you question it does seem that you don't have the file where the error message expects it to be.

Comment: Thank you @AllInOne. I didn't know that exists. I will ask the question there too.

Answer (score 0):

Per the EE 2.7.3 docs found [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html):

> Changed in version 2.6: Relationships was completely rewritten for this version, adding the ability to create multiple relationships for each entry and introducing a friendly new tag syntax. The template tags described here are not compatible with previous versions.

The foundation of Relationships is very different in the new version, so I would guess that you need an update to which ever third party add-on you're using.